# Invalid column name 'FinalTotal'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    o.OrderID, ProductName, OrderDate, ItemPrice, TaxAmount, 
    DiscountAmount, DiscountAmount - ItemPrice AS FinalTotal, 
    Quantity, ShipDate,FinalTotal * Quantity AS ItemTotal
FROM
    Orders AS o 
JOIN 
    OrderItems AS oi ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
JOIN 
    Products AS p ON oi.ProductID = p.ProductID;
```

Here is my code, it keeps saying invalid column name 'FinalTotal'. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `FinalTotal * Quantity` -> `(DiscountAmount - ItemPrice) * Quantity`

Answer (score 5):

you can't use a column alias on the same query level like that.

use the full expression of FinalToal in the calculation of ItemTotal

```
SELECT o.OrderID, ProductName, OrderDate, ItemPrice, TaxAmount, DiscountAmount,
       DiscountAmount - ItemPrice AS FinalTotal, 
       Quantity, ShipDate,
       (DiscountAmount - ItemPrice) * Quantity AS ItemTotal
FROM Orders AS o JOIN OrderItems AS oi
    ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
 JOIN Products AS p
    ON oi.ProductID = p.ProductID;
```

alternatively is to use derived query or CTE

Comment: Thank you, I will try that now.

Answer (score 3):

One trick for doing this in SQL Server is to use `apply`:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, ProductName, OrderDate, ItemPrice, TaxAmount, 
       DiscountAmount, x.FinalTotal, Quantity, ShipDate,
       x.FinalTotal * Quantity AS ItemTotal
FROM Orders o JOIN
     OrderItems AS oi
     ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID JOIN
     Products AS p
     ON oi.ProductID = p.ProductID CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT (DiscountAmount - ItemPrice) as FinalTotal) x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference a derived value within the same query

Try

```
SELECT o.OrderID
, ProductName
, OrderDate
, ItemPrice
, TaxAmount
, DiscountAmount
,DiscountAmount - ItemPrice AS FinalTotal
, Quantity
, ShipDate
,(DiscountAmount - ItemPrice) * Quantity AS ItemTotal
FROM Orders AS o JOIN OrderItems AS oi
    ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
 JOIN Products AS p
    ON oi.ProductID = p.ProductID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, Because There is no column called FinalTotal in your table , this is a computed one

use the following instead ...

```
        SELECT o.OrderID, ProductName, OrderDate, ItemPrice, TaxAmount, DiscountAmount,
       DiscountAmount - ItemPrice AS FinalTotal, 
       Quantity, ShipDate,
       (DiscountAmount - ItemPrice) * Quantity AS ItemTotal
FROM Orders AS o JOIN OrderItems AS oi
    ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
 JOIN Products AS p ON oi.ProductID = p.ProductID;
```